# React-bootstrap how to horizontally center an element only taking account of it's parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox, react-bootstrap

[image]

Hello, I am using react-bootstrap library. I want to center the search bar and button on the navbar. But while centering, it's also taking into account the sibling element (logo) and leaning towards the right of the page. I don't want to solve this by applying brute force minus margin-left if possible. I'm confused with these justify-content stuff. Thanks in advance.

```
<Navbar style={{ backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3" }}>
  <Nav className="d-flex justify-content-start">
    <NavbarBrand href="/">
      <img src={logo} alt="pokedex-logo" style={{ width: 250, marginLeft: 20 }} />
    </NavbarBrand>
  </Nav>
  <Nav className="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center">
    <Form className="d-inline-flex">
      <FormControl
        type="search"
        placeholder="Type pokemon name"
        value={search}
        onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Button
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffe031", color: "#396bba" }}
        onClick={() => history.push(`/pokemon/${search}`)}
      >
        <strong>Search</strong>
      </Button>
    </Form>
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<Navbar style={{ backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3", display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'start' }}>
    <NavbarBrand href="/">
        <img src={logo} alt="pokedex-logo" style={{ width: 250 }} />
    </NavbarBrand>
    <Form className="" style={{ margin: 'auto' }}>
        <FormControl type="search" placeholder="Type pokemon name" value={search} onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffe031", color: "#396bba" }} onClick={() => history.push(`/pokemon/${search}`)}>
            <strong>Search</strong>
        </Button>
    </Form>
</Navbar>
```

Here, the **Navbar** has display flex and the flex direction is row so the logo along with the 2 search elements (text field and search button) will be shown in a row. Then `alignItems:'center'` centers these 3 elements **vertically** in the Navbar and the `justifyContent: 'start'` moves the 3 elements to the start of the Navbar **horizontally**.
After this, to make the 2 elements of search come in the center, `margin:'auto'` is used in the **Form**.

---

And here's another way: (if the above code doesn't correctly align the search elements in center)

```
<Navbar style={{ position: 'relative', display: 'flex', backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3" }}>
    <NavbarBrand href="/" style={{float: 'left'}}>
        <img src={logo} alt="pokedex-logo" style={{ width: 250 }} />
    </NavbarBrand>
    <Form style={{ float: 'none', position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)' }}>
        <FormControl type="search" placeholder="Type pokemon name" value={search} onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffe031", color: "#396bba" }} onClick={() => history.push(`/pokemon/${search}`)}>
            <strong>Search</strong>
        </Button>
    </Form>
</Navbar>
```

In this code, the CSS properties of position and float are used. `float: 'left'` moves the logo to the left and the search elements have `float: 'none'`. The search elements use the position property to align to the center of the Navbar which has `position: 'relative'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the first option did the same. However, the second one works great. I wanted to do this with react-bootstrap but, I think I spent enough time on this. I will continue with the second approach that you've provided.

Comment: That's great to know! And yes the first one wasn't correctly centering the search elements.